# What does 'Error(var)' in ANOVAs with repeated measures means? How is it calculated?

Tags: anova, spss, error

I checked several tutorials, books and online resources, but still I do not know what 'Error(var)' in Anova with repeated measures come from? How is it calculated? I see that number of measures influence the results, but I do not understad why. Image with sample results from SPSS in attachment. When we are refering to the results we need to give an information about this Error(var) df, for example F(2, 12) = XXX.

[image: Sample results from SPSS. Error(time) DF = 12, but why exactly?]

Comment: I think the first thing to worry about if why all your F values are exactly 1. That looks most odd to me.

Comment: @mdewey Hi! Thanks for the reply. It's just a image from the Internet, I just wanted to illustrate 'sample' output.  The thing that I'm interested in is df results in Error(var) row. Which components influence the result? I know that number of observations (rows) in the table affect the df in Error(var), but I wanted to know more. Thanks!